# Kerberos kinit: Unknown credential cache type while getting default ccache

Tags: kerberos, mit-kerberos

I'm using Kerberos on Bash and am attempting to run the kinit command.

I keep getting this error:

```
kinit: Unknown credential cache type while getting default ccache
```

This error also appears for literally any other Kerberos command I run (`klist`, `kdestroy`, etc.).

I've set KRB5CCNAME to the following value: KEYRING:persistent:{uid}

```
[libdefaults]
dns_lookup_realm = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
rdns = false
# default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
```

Could somebody suggest how to troubleshoot this further? There seems to be little documentation on this particular error.

Comment: Are you logged on as root?

Comment: No I'm not but I should have the credentials to run kinit

Comment: Who are you logged in as?

Answer (score 2):

Just comment the attribute `default_ccache_name`:

```
sudo sed -ri "s/^ default_ccache_name = (.*)/# default_ccache_name = \1/g" /etc/krb5.conf
```

Comment: Another common issue is `kadmin.local: Invalid UID in persistent keyring name while opening default credentials cache`

Comment: **Why** does this fix it? OP mentioned explicitly they've set this setting to its value. Commenting it away is not a solution.